# Parsing a XML file using simplexml_load_file return empty object

Tags: xml, simplexml, php

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
   <aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
    <aws:OperationRequest>
    </aws:OperationRequest>
    <aws:UrlInfoResult>
     <aws:Alexa>
      <aws:TrafficData>
       <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">google.com/</aws:DataUrl> 
       <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank> 
      </aws:TrafficData>
     </aws:Alexa>
    </aws:UrlInfoResult>
    <aws:ResponseStatus xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
     <aws:StatusCode>Success</aws:StatusCode> 
    </aws:ResponseStatus>
   </aws:Response>
  </aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

All i want to parse is rank from this xml document.
while trying so what iam doing is ...

```
        $xml= simplexml_load_file("path of the file saved");
        echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->TrafficData->Rank;
```

but i am getting a error doing so .it says

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\SEO Stats[Only Testing]\Tools\web_worth.php on line 13
```

the error is in this line

```
 echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->TrafficData->Rank;
 this line is referred as line no 13..
```

Comment: echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->TrafficData->Rank;

Comment: Just print_r($xml); and check what is its contents

Comment: it give SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parser was returning an empty object because according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) you have to specify the prefixed namespace - so for example you want to use something like:

```
simplexml_load_file('/path/to/file.xml', null, null, 'aws', true);
```

[working example](http://ideone.com/ucSJWJ)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got the result object nesting wrong, thus one of the objects in `$xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa->TrafficData->Rank;` is null. Try `echo`ing every step separately:

```
echo $xml->Response;
echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult;
// etc ...
```

If the first echo returns nothing, then check if you need to output `UrlInfoResponse` instead or need to register namespaces first.

Comment: i did try echo them one by one ..                                      Till echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult its show's nothing on screen and when i try to do this echo $xml->Response->UrlInfoResult->Alexa; It come up with a error..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is too vague, but you can always print the $xml value to see if it is actually an object or not, sometimes happens that the path is wrong.
Try this code to see if the xml document is actually loaded:

```
<?php

if (file_exists('/path/to/document.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('/path/to/document.xml');

    print_r($xml);
} else {
    exit('Failed to open /path/to/document.xml.');
}
```

?>

With this you should see the content of the xml document.

Comment: yes it's loading properlya and print_r($xml gives)           SimpleXMLElement Object ( )