# Why simplexml_load_file not parsing/getting all sub-items?

Tags: php, xml, rss

i am trying to get remote `RSS feed` content in `PHP array` and do some stuff on it.,
i am using `simplexml_load_file`  to convert `RSS` in to an `Array`

e.g.

```
<?php
$raw_array = simplexml_load_file('https://kickass.to/new/rss/');
print_r($raw_array);
?>
```

gives output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => Latest New Torrents RSS Feed - KickassTorrents
            [link] => http://kat.cr/
            [description] => Latest New Torrents RSS Feed
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => title
                            [category] => category
                            [author] => http://kat.cr/user/author/
                            [link] => http://kat.cr/link.html
                            [guid] => http://kat.cr/link.html
                            [pubDate] => Mon, 18 May 2015 16:02:48 +0000
                            [enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => http://torcache.net/torrent/hash.torrent
                                            [length] => 83475908
                                            [type] => application/x-bittorrent
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

but when i go to RSS FEED directly and view source , it shows .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:torrent="http://xmlns.ezrss.it/0.1/">
<channel>
    <title>Latest New Torrents RSS Feed - KickassTorrents</title>
    <link>http://kat.cr/</link>
    <description>Latest New Torrents RSS Feed</description>
    <item>
        <title>titletitletitle</title>

        <category>category- Video</category>
      <author>http://kat.cr/user/author/</author>        <link>http://kat.cr/link.html</link>
        <guid>http://kat.cr/guid.html</guid>
        <pubDate>Mon, 18 May 2015 15:36:42 +0000</pubDate>
        <torrent:contentLength>125153743</torrent:contentLength>
        <torrent:infoHash>212E859FB1BAFEA38BAB91BF3D94BB0DBB0ABFE4</torrent:infoHash>
        <torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA[magnet:?xt=urn:btih:212E859FB1BAFEA38BAB91BF3D94BB0DBB0ABFE4&dn=titletitle=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce]]></torrent:magnetURI>
        <torrent:seeds>0</torrent:seeds>
        <torrent:peers>0</torrent:peers>
        <torrent:verified>1</torrent:verified>
        <torrent:fileName>fileName.torrent</torrent:fileName>
        <enclosure url="http://torcache.net/torrent/212E859FB1BAFEA38BAB91BF3D94BB0DBB0ABFE4.torrent?title=[kat.cr]the.art.of.cocksucking.pir.te" length="125153743" type="application/x-bittorrent" />
    </item>
```

so when i use `simplexml_load_file`  not all sub items/elements are getting parsed/fetched, its missing the items like these

```
        <torrent:contentLength>125153743</torrent:contentLength>
        <torrent:infoHash>212E859FB1BAFEA38BAB91BF3D94BB0DBB0ABFE4</torrent:infoHash>
        <torrent:magnetURI><![CDATA[magnet:?xt=urn:btih:212E859FB1BAFEA38BAB91BF3D94BB0DBB0ABFE4&dn=titletitle=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337%2Fannounce]]></torrent:magnetURI>
        <torrent:seeds>0</torrent:seeds>
        <torrent:peers>0</torrent:peers>
        <torrent:verified>1</torrent:verified>
        <torrent:fileName>fileName.torrent</torrent:fileName>
<torrent:fileName>wwe.payback.2015.ppv.hdtv.x264.champions.rarbg.torrent</torrent:fileName>
```

how can i get values from these  elements too ?

---

ref: [Parsing a XML file using simplexml_load_file return empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787198/parsing-a-xml-file-using-simplexml-load-file-return-empty-object)

i have tried this method from above url , by specifying the namespace.

```
<?php
$raw_array = simplexml_load_file('https://kickass.to/new/rss/', null, null, 'torrent', true);
print_r($raw_array);
?>
```

but it gives empty object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

So how can i get all the elements from this RSS FEED, i can think of other way is fetching the feed using PHP curl and doing preg_match to find tags and their inside values, but it would be ugly fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: see answer with `children()`-method in the above post.